# Sum of an array from class variable java

Tags: java

I just started OOP java and im struggling with getting a sum of my class type elements from an array. Can anyone help me?
hwComponents is a list type of a class HardwareComponent. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private Collection<HardwareComponent> hwComponents = new ArrayList<>();
public float calculatePrice() 
{

float sum=0;
for (int i=1;i < hwComponents.size(); i++) 
    sum+= hwComponents.get(i); //The method get(i) is undefined for this type
    return sum;

}
```

Comment: What is the value from the class `HardwareComponent` that you want to `sum`? A *price* perhaps? So something like `return hwComponents.stream().mapToDouble(HardwareComponent::getPrice).sum();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Collection` doesn't have a `get(index)` method.

Store your `ArrayList` in a `List` variable instead:

```
private List<HardwareComponent> hwComponents = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also note that the indices of your loop should begin at 0.

As an alternative, you can use an enhanced for loop, which doesn't require the `get` method:

```
for (HardwareComponent hc : hwComponents) {
    sum+= hc.getSomeProperty(); // note that HardwareComponent cannot be added to 
              // a float (or to anything else for that matter, so you probably
              // intended to call some method of your class which returns a float
}
```

Comment: @MauricePerry yes, I just addressed that issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to change the type of your array/collection, you just need to iterate through the collection in the collections defined order:

```
sum = 0;
for( HardwareComponent hc: hwComponents)
    sum += hc.cost;
return sum;
```